# Gestures on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I wanted to add gestures on Ubuntu like windows but I am having a hard time getting a smooth zoom in and out using two finger pinch in softwares? I used lib input and touchegg with no success they are too laggy, is there some other way?